# Unsure why I failed this "Low-quality posts" review audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I know these types of questions get posted here a lot, and I've read through several of them trying to understand my specific scenario, but I am still not clear.

This low-quality post review:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25083683

was failed by me after I said "Looks OK", and I was banned from the queue for 2 days, even though I have a positive review history in the Low Quality Post queue and can't remember the last time I failed an audit.

The answer in question that I reviewed seems to answer the question -- whether or not it's the correct answer, I am not sure, but I consider this post to be a good attempt at answering the question. Like all of my Low Quality Posts reviews, I read through the answer several times in the context of the question before choosing my vote.

Could someone help me understand what I did wrong here? I want to make sure I am fully understanding the meaning of the Low Qualtiy Posts review queue.

Comment: that answer is spam deleted.

Comment: The answer text itself looks fine at the first glance, but the link is a red flag. It links to the same page mentioned in the user profile without mentioning the authorship, thus _could_ already qualify as spam. Since this question has been deleted (instead of updated to add the required remark) I guess this user wrote several such answers containing a link to their site.

Comment: As there is only one down vote I suspect a mod spam flagged it. I can't find that post in the usual spam tooling/chatrooms either.

Comment: Definitely something unusual there. It is exceedingly rare to have a single answer locked like that. I don't think this was a good post for the review.

Comment: Yes, it was a moderator who flagged that one as spam. And 3 other answers by the same user. It definitely wasn't a good case for a review audit, but spam flags do get used as a signal for a good audit because they *usually* are. Not a big deal; you could have passed the audit easily by clicking through to examine the post in context.

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback guys, I appreciate it. It seems like clicking through the link reveals the spammy nature of this post. I usually only check links when approving link edits in the Edit queue, but checking them in LQ posts makes sense in this context as well.

Comment: You don't need to click on the link (I wouldn't click on unknown links in any case), it is often enough to check the URL of the link.

Comment: Ah, I do not mean to click the suspected spammy link in the post. I mean the link named "link" in the right-hand margin of the audit page, which will display the actual post in context, rather than inside of the review queue. As a moderator, who reviews hundreds of suspected spam posts daily, I don't click on *any* of the links in the posts themselves.

Comment: Right, that makes more sense. Glad to know I don't have to click on any of them, I was worried because I hadn't been doing that in the first place (unless it's someone trying to edit a post with a fresh link to documentation)

Comment: It does work well to hover over the links inside of a post (without clicking) and read your browser's status bar to see where the link is planning to take you. That often is enough to tell the difference between a well-intended link to documentation and a link to nonsense.